# how to prevent duplicate data

Tags: php, mysqli, duplicates

I'm trying to insert data in database from multiple table and 
I want to prevent the data from duplicating and it works, but

it does not work when there is a new data inserted, it still insert the new data except with all previous data exist. how can i prevent it from duplicating.

I had try INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY but is it possible to take values from multiple table. How?

This is my code. tmno is userID

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('configure.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$tmno = $_SESSION['tmno'];
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
$month = $_SESSION['month'];
$paymentID = $_SESSION['paymentID'] ;
$cartID = $_SESSION['cartID'];
$statusName = $_SESSION['statusName'];
$feeID = $_SESSION['feeID'];

$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE paymentID='$paymentID' AND feeID='$feeID'");
$checkrows = mysqli_num_rows($check);
if($checkrows){
echo "<script>alert('Already Update!');
            window.location='AdminFee.php'</script>";
}
else{ 

$yo = "INSERT IGNORE INTO invoice (paymentID,cartID,date,feeID,month,tmno,statusName)
       SELECT payment.paymentID, cart.cartID,payment.date,fee.feeID,fee.month,cart.tmno,payment.statusName
       FROM payment
       inner join cartitem on payment.cartID = cartitem.cartID
       inner join fee on cartitem.feeID = fee.feeID
       inner join cart on payment.cartID = cart.cartID";

$keputusan = mysqli_query($con,$yo);

    if($keputusan){

    echo "<script>alert('Invoice Updated!');
            window.location='AdminFee.php'</script>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<script>alert('Failed to Update Invoice!');
            window.location='AdminFee.php'</script>";
    }

}
}
?>
```

[Database Image : the red box show the duplication data and the yellow box show the new data inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nymAI.png)

Comment: You need to use Primary keys and check if that value exists before inserting to avoid duplicates. And, of course you can take data from multiple tables. You are already using join.

Comment: Unless you are learning for school or you have specific requirements, there are many nice query builders that will make your interactions much easier such as Eloquent. You can also use PHP frameworks such as Larval and Codeigniter

Comment: You can define a multi-column unique constraint on the columns which must be unique. It looks like these would be many columns, I can't tell which, you know your database better than me.

Comment: Adding the unique constrain really do the job.Thanks